# String variable returns empty despite being assigned a value

Tags: excel, vba, global-variables

I have a UserForm, what I do is open a workbook from a dialogbox then create a new workbook based on a template. I want to assign both files' names + extension (.xlsm) to a string which I'll use in a copy method.

I'm a beginner with VBA everything is the userform's code:

```
Public Sub Btn1_Click()
Dim FileName1 As String
Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Choose file to poen", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsm*),*xls*")
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        TextBox1.Value = FileToOpen
    End If
FileName1 = OpenBook.Name
End Sub
```

```
Public Sub Btn2_Click()
Dim FileName2 As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim fPth As Object
Set fPth = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

If choice1 = True Then
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add("path to file template 1")
ElseIf choice2 = True Then
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add("path to file template 2")
End If

With fPth
  .InitialFileName = Filename & ".xlsm"
  .Title = "Please choose a name for your new file"
  .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
  If .Show <> 0 Then
    wb.SaveAs Filename:=.SelectedItems(1), FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
  End If
End With
FileName2 = wb.Name
End Sub
```

All I'm trying to do is use FileName1 and FileName2 in my copy method which I'll assign to a button as well and will run once both files are open.

If I add a MsgBox to show either variable directly after assigning values to them, they do return the file's name. When I use the MsgBox in a random button I added for testing purposes, they simply return empty. All my methods are set as public.

Comment: Reading about [variable scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-scope-and-visibility) should be helpful.

Comment: I was reading that article specifically, might have missed some points but I have tried setting the variable to Public (which returned an error) from Dim, then Static (same result) and back to Dim. So not entirely sure. What to do.

Comment: Put `Option Explicit` on top of your code, observe the result, then consult the scope article again.

Comment: I can't read. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit
Public FileName1 As String
Public FileName2 As String
```

At the start of my module solves the issue.